# Calculating Peltier efficiency

Tags: thermoelectricity

This is half Skeptics SE , half here.

Please help me proving this [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/metaura/metaura-pro-world-1st-wearable-ac-that-blows-cold-air-flow) is baloney. Besides the stupid marketing claims what we have here is a neck band shaped portable device of 180x177x45mm total size which utilizes Peltier cooling operated from a 6000 mAh battery to provide 7F cooler air to the wearer up to 2.5 hours. There's a 8W "rated power" whatever that means -- I will observe that gets pretty close the theoretical maximum you can get from the battery that is 6 mAh * 3.7V / 2.5 hours. I am reasonably sure this can't possibly work as claimed. What does physics has to say on this?

Comment: Are people actually paying money for this thing? How can anyone possibly think that a neck device that may or may not blow cooler air keep your entire body cool?